# Will we litteraly see G-d in Olam HaBa?

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come

G-d is uncorporeal. Which mean He doesn't have a physical form . When HaKadosh Baruch Hu appeared to the elders in Exodus and to other prophets, He just appeared this way so to let them know His presence (correct me if I am mistaken here please).

Will we litteraly see G-d ? Or we will just feel and see His Glory (presence) like in the biblical times ?

Comment: if He is uncorporeal what is there to see?

Comment: @ray I really don't know, but I have the curiosity to know how all the world will get to know G-d like if all it's inhabitants are like prophets..

Comment: is that the same question?

Comment: I think this is a question of semantics. If God is incorporeal, it doesn't make any sense to say that one can _literally_ see God (In other words: "What @ray said").

Comment: @Daniel indeed, but what will be seeing then ? His glory ? His "appearance" to us ? or something else ?

Comment: @mil Maybe we won't _literally_ see anything.

Comment: @Daniel good point. Since I heard before that the world will continue normally in the Messianic era, but Olam HaBa is completely different world.

Comment: No one can truly answer this since (as far as I know) no one has been there and come back to talk about it. However it is important to remember that the same rules that apply here do not apply there. There isn't necessarily physical sight in Olam HaBa. For example in our world talking is a way to communicate but that isn't necessarily how communication occurs in that world. Essentially our understanding is too limited to be able to know.

Comment: @yitzih I think the answer is yes, we will see Him. With _real_ vision, not the mashalic physical vision we are stuck with in Olam Hazeh

Answer (score 3):

See the Bartenura in [Shanhedrin 10:1](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01309.html#HtmpReportNum0059_L2) who describes it such:

> וְהָעוֹלָם הַבָּא אֵין בּוֹ לֹא אֲכִילָה וְלֹא שְׁתִיָּה, וְאַף עַל פִּי שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ גוּף וּגְוִיָּה, אֶלָּא צַדִּיקִים יוֹשְׁבִין וְעַטְרוֹתֵיהֶן בְּרָאשֵׁיהֶן וְנֶהֱנִין מִזִּיו הַשְּׁכִינָה

In Olam HaBa there is no eating nor drinking, even though we will be corporeal; rather the righteous will sit with their crowns on their heads <sub>(i.e. their spiritual achievements visible)</sub> and enjoy the Divine presence.

Comment: And even with that said, there are also many meforshim who emphasize that in particular with Moshiach'feast, meaning the feast on leviathan and shor habor, it will be an actual, physical meal after which they will bench on a kos shel brachah.

Comment: @YaacovDeane - and that means "Will we literally see G-d ?" as OP wants to know...

Comment: See my comment to Daniel above. Like is brought by Rabbi Meir Ibn Gabbai in Sefer Avodat HaKodesh, it appears the stage of "Olam HaBa", meaning the world of resurrection will also have stages. And part of that will be physical in the more conventional sense. Ramchal in Pinot HaMerkava and Chamaui Gaon in Sefer Brit Menucha also indicate as much. They address the three millenia after the Yovel meaning after the year 7000.

Answer (score 2):

Paraphrasing a discourse of the Lubavitcher Rebbe from parshat Beshallach:

When the Jewish people went through the parting of the Sea, they were able to perceive G-d's presence so clearly that they were able to point with their finger and say, "This (zeh) is my G-d." Even this, however, will not compare with our ability to experience G-dliness in the Messianic Age, when there will be an incomparably higher revelation. For G-d has told the Jewish people, "At the parting of the Sea you said, `this' (zeh) only once, but in the Messianic Age you will say`this' (zeh) twice, as we find in the prophecy Isaiah (25:9), "You will say on that day, `Behold this (zeh) is my G-d. We have trusted Him and He has redeemed us; this (zeh) is G-d who we have trusted, let us rejoice and be happy in His redemption.' "

Comment: So will we literally see God?

Comment: @Daniel What are you meaning by "literally"? According to the explanation, as much as such a thing is possible, it would seem to be the case. But at the same time, this doesn't deny or overturn any requirements or teachings that exist in Torah. The nature of the world will be different at that point than it is now.

Comment: You'd have to ask the OP what _he_ means by "literally."

Comment: @Daniel Perhaps a different way of thinking about this is that we will not see any place as devoid of G-d. Where in the present, it appears otherwise. We may have an intellectual concept or sense that G-d everywhere, but then we will actually see this through our physical senses to the extent that we can point at it with our finger. This is just like when we point at the matzah during the Seder and say, "This matzah that we eat..."

Comment: So is your answer, "no"?

Comment: @Daniel As surprising as the answer might sound and with all the caveats I have mentioned, I would be more inclined to say yes.

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of vision: one is with the physical eyes, a blind person will say "I see" to mean "I understand", and what the prophet sees is a prophetic notion which he translates as "I saw" and describes in words. So too, in Olam haBa "vision" can be understood to mean according to the awareness of the soul - but **we** have no notion of that, as the Sages say "עין לא ראתה" - no one (of us living in this world) has seen that, and therefore we do NOT know what it is.

Comment: The Sages said that עין לא ראתה only about Eden, not about Gan (Eden), and not Olam Habah, and the Diyuk isn't about "those living in this world"